# set angular component variable value in an HTML5 data attribute

Tags: html, angular, data-binding, attributes

I have a 



 that its css has before with **content** that depends on the **li** attribute:

```
::before
{
   content:attr(data-datetime)
}
```

The Html that works:

```
<li class="timeline-seperator" data-datetime="01/2020"></li>
```

The problem is that I would like the **data-datetime** attribute takes its value from the angular component function\variable (and not a fixed value as seen here)

Is there a way to make it  ?

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Angular](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w2rv4g)

u can do it for custom attribute like `attr.` to bind

```
<li class="timeline-seperator"  [attr.data-datetime]="name"></li>
```

or

```
<li class="timeline-seperator"  attr.data-datetime="{{name}}"></li>
```